# Get content of component tag in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I just started playing around with Vue. I want to do something like this:

```html
<snippet name="Select From Table">
  SELECT *
  FROM database.table
</snippet>
```

And to have that produce a link that when clicked calls a function that has access to the SQL.

I tried using a component, but I don't know how to get the SQL in the click function so I can use it. Slots looks interesting, but that only seems to work inside the tag and not in attributes.

Thanks!

Comment: This feels like an XY problem. Why can’t the MySQL command be sent in like a prop? And more importantly... you shouldn’t be allowing client side scripting to send in any mysql commands whatsoever. It’s a huge security risk.

Comment: Not to be worried, this is just an internal tool, but thanks anyways!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to grab the content of the slot, you have to loop `this.$slots.slotName` then get the innerText or innerHtml you need.

PS: as @Terry mentioned, allow the client side to execute any SQL command will be a huge security risk.

Like **below demo**:

```js
Vue.component('v-test',{
    template:`
        <div>
          <a @click.stop="addText()">{{current}}</a>
        </div>
    `,
    data () {
      return {
        current: 'Bla'
      }
    },
    methods: {
      addText: function () {
        this.current += 'Bla'
      }
    }
})
Vue.component('snippet',{
    template:`
        <div style="border: 1px solid grey" @click="getHtml()">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
    `,
    methods: {
      getHtml: function () {
        alert(this.$slots.default && Object.values(this.$slots.default).map((item, index) => {
          return item.elm && (item.elm.wholeText || item.elm.innerText)
        }).join('\r\n'))
      }
    }
})

new Vue ({
  el:'#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div class="container">
        <snippet>Test SQL ...</snippet>
        <br>
        <snippet><strong>Te<i>s<span>.</span></i>t</strong> SQL ...</snippet>
        <br>
        <snippet><strong>Test<v-test></v-test></strong> SQL ...</snippet>
    </div>
</div>
```

Another solution will be use `ref`.

```js
Vue.component('v-test',{
    template:`
        <div>
          <a @click.stop="addText()">{{current}}</a>
        </div>
    `,
    data () {
      return {
        current: 'Bla'
      }
    },
    methods: {
      addText: function () {
        this.current += 'Bla'
      }
    }
})
Vue.component('snippet',{
    template:`
        <div style="border: 1px solid grey" @click="getHtml()" ref="test">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
    `,
    methods: {
      getHtml: function () {
        alert(this.$refs.test.innerText)
      }
    }
})

new Vue ({
  el:'#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div class="container">
        <snippet>Test SQL ...</snippet>
        <br>
        <snippet><strong>Te<i>s<span>.</span></i>t</strong> SQL ...</snippet>
        <br>
        <snippet><strong>Test<v-test></v-test></strong> SQL ...</snippet>
    </div>
</div>
```